# MongoDB schema to store directories with JSON files

Tags: mongodb, database-schema

Suppose I've got a lot of JSON files stored in a file system, e.g.

```
├── a
│   ├── a-1.json
│   ├── a-2.json
│   ├── a1
│   │   └── a11
│   │       ├── a11-1.json
│   │       └── a11-2.json
│   └── a2
│       └── a2-1.json
├── b
│   └── b1
│       ├── b1-1.json
│       └── b1-2.json
└── c
    └── c-1.json
```

Now I need to store all these JSON files with the directory structure in a MongoDB.
So I want to create two collections: "files" and "dirs". The "files" collection contains the JSON files.

```
 { "id" : 12345, "name" : "a-1", ... }
 { "id" : 67890, "name" : "a-2", ... }
```

The "dirs" collection contains documents that correspond to the directories. For instance:

```
{"a" : {files: [12345, 67890], "a1:" : {"a11": {files: [...]}}, "a2" : {...}}
{"b" : {"b1" : {files: [...]}}}
{"c" : {files: [...]}}
```

Does this schema make sense?

Comment: Maybe `{folder: "\a\a1\a11", files: [ "a11-1.json", "a11-2.json"] }` is more generic

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Why do you file names instead of `id` ? The file names are not unique.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You are right. My comment is not clear. I wonder why you use an array of file names `files: ["a11-1.json", "a11-2.json"]` rather than an array of _ids_, e, g, `files: [<id of a11-1.json>, <id of a11-2.json>]`

Comment: Up to you, what is "<id of a11-1.json>"? A file has a file name, what else? (apart from some filesystem internal stuff). For sure it is not a smart idea to define 2 collections. Use only one! NoSQL Databases like MonogDB are not relational databases like Oracle or MySQL. Lookups should be avoided, they are not optimized for it and some NoSQL systems do not support lookup at all.

Comment: I store all these files as documents in Mongo. <id of a11-1.json> is the `id` of the Mongo document, that contains the content of "a11-1.json".

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for the suggestion of using only one collection. I got it !

Answer (score 1):

Two strategy

You can create one record per file with full path in it.

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "/a/a1/a11/a11-1.json" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "/a/a1/a11/a11-2.json" }
```

Easy to add/remove file and search. This is how it's done in S3.

If you really don't want redundant data then you need to create node / child model.

For parent = parent _id or 0 for root
For type 0 = directory, 1 = file.

```
{ "_id"  : 1, "parent" : 0, "type" : 0, "name" : "a" }
{ "_id"  : 2, "parent" : 1, "type" : 0, "name" : "a1" }
{ "_id"  : 3, "parent" : 2, "type" : 0, "name" : "a11" }
{ "_id"  : 4, "parent" : 3, "type" : 1, "name" : "a11-1.json" }
{ "_id"  : 5, "parent" : 3, "type" : 1, "name" : "a11-2.json" }
```

More complex to maintain.

Avoid to use array if you don't know how many files you can have in one directory because there is a document size limitation of 16 MB. Loading a 16 MB document is not very optimal.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like solution #1. Now I just wonder how to search for all files in a given folder. Would it be efficient to search for all files with path "/a/a1" ?

Comment: Use regex. For exemple Find({ "name": /^\/a\/a1\/a11\/.*/i }) will give all files in directory a11. Add an index on name for more efficiency.

Comment: Looks nice. Thanks !